# Nginx - can't get remote access to server [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: nginx, server, gunicorn

I enabled Nginx on my server, the site-enabled file is:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }
    }
```

I do redirect to localhost because I raised Gunicorn for flask application.

I try to get remote access from other machine by ip, but I don't get any response. Even if I use 
`curl http:X.X.X.X` on my server machine
it says `access denied`

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi! Wellcome to SO. Quality questions give you quality answer. I suggest you to bring us more information about your system. For example Is your server behind a firewall? Have your opened the port 80 of your server for incoming and outgoing requests? Can you request to your gunicorn from localhost? Could be a lot of problems in your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked logs?

Default log path for nginx is **/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

If you have only one virtualhost add **default** after **listen 80**.

```
listen 80 default;
```

Complete config is:

```
    server {
       listen 80 default;
       server_name YOUR_DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.com;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/EXAMPLE.access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/EXAMPLE.error.log;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

       }
}
```